# 3 listbox alignment on a webpage

Tags: asp.net, listbox, css

I have this scenario. I need to show 3 list boxes on a ASP.NET web page. List box A would have all the options on page load and list boxes B, C would be empty.

I want to align all three such that I can select items from A to B and A to C. So, A would be shown as a bigger listbox with B, and C as smaller boxes on to its right such that B and C are vertically aligned. Of course B and C would have their respective set of 'Add', 'Add all', 'Remove', 'Remove All' buttons.

```
--------------            --------------
|            |            |            |
| ListBox A  | >  >> << < | ListBox B  |
|            |            |            |
|            |            --------------
|            |            --------------
|            | >  >> << < | List Box C |
|            |            |            |
--------------            --------------
```

Please point me to the appropriate css style examples.

cheers

Comment: Your description of the user interface is not complete enough to help us envision what you want to do.  Have you attempted to build this yet?  Can you provide us with what you have so far?  If not can you provide a mock-up or a sketch of the interface so we have something to work with?

Comment: Yep, my bad there. I have somewhat sketched what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does following design helps you?

```
<div style="border: solid 1px red; width: 650px;">
    <div style="border: solid 1px blue; float: left; height:400px; width: 200px;">
        ListBox A</div>
    <div style="border: solid 1px blue; float: left; height:400px; width: 200px">
        <div style="padding-top:40%; vertical-align:middle; width: 200px;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top:90%; width: 200px;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="border: solid 1px blue; float: left; height:400px; width: 200px;">
        <div style="border: solid 1px black; height:200px; width: 200px">
        ListBox B
        </div>
        <div style="border: solid 1px black; height:200px; width: 200px">
        ListBox C
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: left;">&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```